# Maclaurin expasion of $\sin(x)/(1-4x^2)$

Tags: calculus

I have to expand this function $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1-4x^2}$ around $x=0$ and then find tis radius of convergence.

I expand $\sin(x)$ on series, but i dont know how to use $1/(1-4x^2)$, it is the same that

$1/(1-(2x)^2)$

but I will get the product of two series, is there any other way to do it?
Thak you

Comment: Just do it from scratch? 

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

Comment: Using the fact that $\frac1{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots$, we have $$\frac1{1-4x^2} = 1 + 4x^2 + (4x^2)^2 + (4x^2)^3 + \ldots$$Now multiply this by the series for $\sin x$.

Comment: /ed_4434, syes, but i wanted to know if there is other way

Comment: Theophile, thank you, but how can i get the radius from that?